# The import src cannot be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I'm a beginner in JSP but understand Java and HTML. I am running into this error when trying to run a JSP file in Eclipse on line three, can someone please help?

[image: The following link is my Path Layout]

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <%@page import = "src/Person.java" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An import directive in a JSP is just like an `import` statement in a Java source file: it expects a fully-qualified class name, not a path to a source file.

First of all, you must put your class `Person` in a package. Put the source file `MyPerson.java` in a directory `mypackage`, for example, and add a `package` statement at the top of the source file:

```
package mypackage;
```

Then, you can import it in the JSP by specifying the fully-qualified class name:

```
<%@page import="mypackage.Person" %>
```

Comment: One thing that confused me as a beginner was the packaging naming structure. OP, [here's a good resource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html) on how to name a package.

Comment: Thank You soo much for your help, I really appreciate it

Comment: The least important directive in a JSP file is the import statement, because there is never any reason to put java code in a JSP file. You should use the JSP file as a view component not a controller or a model component.